# Error Handling with SecItemCopyMatching and Veracode

Tags: ios, swift

I use Veracode to scan my application and have the error about 
Unchecked Error Condition. Here is my code:

```
    let status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &queryResult) {
        SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
    }

    // Check the return status and throw an error if appropriate.
    guard status != errSecItemNotFound else {
        throw KeychainError.noKeychain
    }
    guard status == noErr else {
        throw KeychainError.unhandledError(status: status)
    }
```

Error is at this line: SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))

> Error handling problems occur when an application does not properly handle errors that occur during processing. If a function does not generate the correct return/status codes, or if the product does not handle all possible return/status codes that could be generated by a function, then security issues may result. Similarly, failing to catch an exception thrown by a function can potentially cause the program to crash or to behave in an unexpected manner.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation of `withUnsafeMutablePointer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2429788-withunsafemutablepointer), the argument in closure is already of `UnsafeMutablePointer` type. So basically you're passing `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer>` to `SecItemCopyMatching`, where (if you want to stick with `UnsafeMutablePointer`) you should be passing `UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef>`. So try

```
SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, $0)
```

Comment: Thank you, I just edit my question. The problem is about return checking so I'm not sure about your answer. I will run the veracode check again and let you know.